# FBLoginView how to check user accepted the publish permission?

Tags: objective-c, facebook, ipad

How do I check user accepted the publish permission when using FBLoginView. I managed to reauthorized a user by asking the publish permission. How do I know the user selected OK on the dialog or Don't Allow inside the handler of the reauthorizedWithPublishPermission function call.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've implemented FBRequestDelegate, FBSessionDelegate, you should get a callback on one of these depending on how the user responds:

FBRequestDelegate:

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
```

FBSessionDelegate:

```
- (void)fbDidNotLogin:(BOOL)cancelled
```

These are in the Facebook API at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/iossdk/

Comment: No I am using the FBLoginView control given from FacebookSDK 3.1